# Update PageRank given extra links

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a stabilized importance vector $x_k$ that is the PageRank of a series of webpages as defined by the links between them. Graphically, this is the equivalent of a graph where nodes are pages and links are directed edges. Assuming a few links are added on a few pages -- graphically, a few directed edges are added -- is there a faster method to converge upon the updated importance vector $x_{k+1}$ that is faster than running the canonical PageRank algorithm?

I am looking for a preconditioning to the PageRank problem that allows for the number of iterations required for convergence to a new stabilized importance vector to be reduced over merely running the PageRank algorithm iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

**This is just a thought**
Note that pagerank algorithm in the end boils down to finding the leading eigenvector corresponding to the non-negative adjacency matrix (entries $\geq0$), traditionally using the power iteration method. Now, you add more edges to the graph, this effectively means you add a non-negative matrix to your original matrix. Say $A$ was the adjaceny matrix of the graph. You add more edges, then the adjacency matrix becomes $B=A+E$, where $E$ is another non-negative matrix which comes because of adding more edges. Thus, now we are interested in the leading eigenvector of $B$. Thus your question is, given a non-negative matrix $A$ and its leading eigenvector $v$, what is the new principal eigenvector after perturbing $A$ with $E$, so that the new matrix of interest is $B$?.

There are indeed general approaches to estimate the leading eigenvector of a perturbed matrix. But how effective they are for your problem is an interesting problem in itself. If you are interested in a hack, then I would suggest running the power iteration again with current principal eigenvector as the initial seed. If the perturbation $E$ is small enough, I guess this should be close enough.

Comment: I tested your convergence hack using the previous principal eigenvector; interestingly, the power iteration on the current principal eigenvector is actually slower and runs in more iterations than starting the candidate vector at $\hat{\frac{1}{n}}$. I think it's because I'm addign more links than I originally thought. This makes the graph/matrix denser, so the solution has the potential to swing around the solution space a lot more than I originally thought it would.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. Do let me (and others) know, what solution you came up with,